# How to make an imported variable transparently call a function

Tags: python

Imagine this situation :

I have a file named *settings.py* that contains

```
from datetime import datetime
FOO = datetime.now()
```

Now, in another file, I do `from django.conf import settings` (the fact that I'm using Django in this specific situation is irrelevant)

In the file I did the import when I use `settings.FOO`, no matter how much time has passed I will always get the same datetime value, which corresponds to the time when the import happened.

I understand how and why it works that way. My question is : Is there a way to always have an updated value "stored" in `settings.FOO` without changing the way I access that value ? (as `settings.FOO` is used in multiple file across multiple subprojects, I aim to keep that syntax)

In other words, I there a way to make my imported variable transparently call a function ?

Comment: All inside variable are cached on first import, use the function to return dynamic data. Or you can reload module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module

Comment: Variables never update themselves automatically. It doesn't matter whether it's imported or local. There's no way to make any variable act like a function.

Comment: However, you can do it with object attributes using the @property declaration. So maybe you should declare a class in `settings.py`. Then you could use `settings_obj.FOO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there's almost never a good reason for doing it like this, and you would almost always rely on explicit callables for doing what you do, but by explicitly manipulating `sys.modules`, if all you care about is syntax, it *is* possible to do what you're trying to do.

`settings.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import sys

class _Bar:
   @property
   def FOO(self):
        return datetime.now()

sys.modules[__name__] = _Bar()
```

Usage example:

```
>>> import settings
>>> settings.FOO
datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 4, 17, 0, 5, 987423)
>>> settings.FOO
datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 4, 17, 0, 7, 285826)
```

Comment: Since this answers my question accepted it. But I've noted your warning and will probably not use it.